# +50 difference between awarded bounty and offered bounty

Tags: support, bounty

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) [offered 5 bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley?tab=bounties&sort=offered) and awarded two of them.

---

**The first offer** was of `+250` on [wxPython: how to get screen x/y for line in a RichTextCtrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797541/wxpython-how-to-get-screen-x-y-for-line-in-a-richtextctrl):

[image]

However the chosen answer has been awarded `+300` which makes a `+50` difference:

[image]

---

**The second offer** was of `+200` on [wxPython: how to create a bash shell window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989129/wxpython-how-to-create-a-bash-shell-window):

[image]

Again, the chosen answer has been awarded `+250` which makes a `+50` difference:

[image]

---

What's wrong?

Comment: Hmm, in the question history it shows the same bounty as shown on the answer for both of your examples.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When bounties were first introduced in 2009, the system added 50 points on the house. From [Reputation Bounty for Unanswered Questions, 2009-01-29](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/):

> (Note that the total bounty award is +50 because we throw in 50 bonus rep on top of whatever reputation you’ve put up.)

This was changed in 2010. From [Improvements to Bounty System](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/):

> The system no longer tosses in +50 bonus reputation to a bounty. We feel this newer, much more open bounty  system no longer needs that incentive.

Comment: Ok. Shouldn't this be explained when we hover the awarded bounty? Something like *"This answer has been awarded bounties worth 250 reputation by Bryan and 50 by **Community**"*, so that it prevents people to wonder what's wrong?

Comment: @Stéphane Bruckert - Good idea, maybe you should add a feature request. I actually looked at your question's title and thought "how can people not know these things?". Then I saw it was 6 years ago. Maybe I'm old.

Comment: WTF? 2009 is already 6 years ago? I'm old!

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert it would be easier to simply fudge the numbers so they match.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Keleven to the rescue! (http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11495/what-does-the-keleven-digit-look-like)

Comment: @MarkRansom I think you are right; I was a about to ask for a feature-request, but I figured out that the `+50` are *offered* by the community but still *awarded* by the initial offerer as part of its main bounty because he's the only one to decide whether the answer deserves it or not.